# Actionscript 3 - How To Check A Random Pixel Of A Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, sprite, pixel

I have a sprite that is drawn in random and complicated way. Pixels would be either transparent or not. And now I need to check if pixel `new Point(10, -5)` is transparent or not.

**How can I do that ?**

---

- This is not for collision detection.
- I also draw in the negative area of the sprite graphics. It is not centered.

---

**Solution:**

The main problem was the drawing in negative area. I figured it out myself:

```
var bitmapData: BitmapData = new BitmapData(sprite.width, sprite.height, true, 0x0);
var rect: Rectangle = sprite.getBounds(sprite);
var mat: Matrix = new Matrix();
mat.translate(-rect.left, -rect.top);
bitmapData.draw(sprite, mat);
bitmapData.getPixel32(xCoordToTest - rect.left, yCoordToTest - rect.top);
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new BitmapData object and draw your sprite onto it. Then check desired BitmapData pixel.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mySprite.width,mySprite.height,true,0x00000000);
bitmapData.draw(mySprite);
bitmapData.getPixel32(10,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like SzRaPnEL says, draw your sprite into a BitmapData object with the 3rd parameter set to true (enabling transparency).
Then...

```
var pixelValue:uint = bitmapData.getPixel32(xCoordToTest, yCoordToTest);
var alphaValue:uint = pixelValue >> 24 & 0xFF;
```

According to the BitmapData online docs, that should work...
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel32()

Comment: You both missed the main problem.